Delete content from PDF using Python
I need to cleanse a large number of PDFs from PDF content and leave only an image inside (the structure of the PDFs is always the same).
Here is a screenshot of the PDF content:

The image marked in yellow is the one I want to keep, all those Paths and Texts and the other smaller image are to be deleted. I have checked out some Python libraries for PDF such as PyPDF but it seems to me like it does not allow me to access that content, only comments and annotations and such stuff.
Does anyone have a solution?

You may want to consider PyMuPDF's redaction feature. This lets you erase content underneath some rectangle, optionally offering to insert stuff inside the emptied space - like an image. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

The Problem with Cadastral (Cable Network) plans. Is they are often tiled thus for one plan you may only want the one image but for another plan you may need 4 or 6 background images.
Here is a similar one and just keeping one image still retains other data.

The reason is the page is composed in a random fashion of mixed vectors colours and other scalar transformations like this.
35 0 obj
<</Length 4257>>
stream
q
.12 0 0 .12 0 0 cm
/R9 gs
q
193 247 3967 4485 re
W
n
q
0 4494.2 -3976.2 0 4160.1 237.9 cm
/R10 Do
Q
Q
q
4717.8 5875.72 m
4717.8 247.063 l
193.012 247.063 l
193.012 6817.49 l
4245.75 6817.49 l
4245.75 5875.72 l
4717.8 5875.72 l
W

This is common facet of programmable charting, plotting or mapping which in reality is how most PDF pages are composited.
Let us presume object 39 is the largest image. It is a JPEG at unknown position
39 0 obj
<</BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/DCTDecode/Height 954/Length 152277/Subtype/Image/Width 1079>>

we know it is part of /XObject<</R10 39 0 R....... but we cannot delete the XObject.
What we see is that we need to delete all the data in 4257 bytes (parts of 35) without removing /R9 or /R10 etc. and without all their prior current matrix (cm transformations). That place them at exactly those placements!
Clearly the easiest programming method (while analysing the problem) is resolve it as X without writing reams of whY code. The Art of Designer programs is knowing when to avoid writing them. Or designing a strategy for bulk design.

Thus all we need to program is how to export the 8 images in one command line. That is easy it is a one line shell command.

However when you see the poor native quality, it is obvious. It really would not be worth it. Quality is 55% of 50% (A really bad abuse of compression.)

